# Run .jar with Specific. path

Tags: java, jar, directory, execute

I want to run from an diffrent dicrectory a .jar when i use `java -jar PATH_TO_FILE` it will be executed in the directory where i run the command. How can I say, that the jar will be start in the directory where the .jar located.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't; not with a command line switch, at any rate. You have 3 broad strategies to fix whatever ailment this causes:

#### Fix your bugs

Evidently, your application is written with the presumption that the 'current working directory' is whereever the jar file. This is a common bug in java code that needs access to e.g. a `png` image file for rendering in e.g. a GUI, or parse a txt file with some static information.

The fix is to not write that code in the first place - the proper mechanism for storing read-only resources with your app is to put them the same place classes are put: Inside jars, by your build system. Put them in `src/main/resources` (assuming you're using maven or something that works similarly), and use `YourClass.class.getResource("open.png")` to read them, not `new File`.

### Stop using the place your jar lives as datastore

Alternatively, if it's read/write files, those shouldn't live where your jar files live: That is a windowsism, and an early 90s windowsism at that: Users should not be presumed to have write access to the place where executables live. The right place for such files are somewhere in the user's home directory (probably a subdir of that), which you can ask for in java with `System.getProperty("user.home")`.

### Write a script

If you must, write a batch script or shell script that does it. There are many ways in posix (so, linux, mac os, etc) to fire off a process in another directory. PowerShell scripts on windows can accomplish similar tasks. This is ugly (and OS dependent), so the first 2 options are much better.

Comment: Thanks, with the Batch files it worked now!